# Firebase push notifications not working in the background when sent from a REST API

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

I need help with notifications in flutter.
I have configured firebase_messaging in my flutter app. When i send test notifications from the firebase console they work in both foreground and background. When i send the notifications from a backend rest api service, they only work in the foreground.I.e only `onMessage` is triggered in this case.

sample notification body from REST API:

```
{notification: {title: null, body: null}, data: {intent: payment, body: 2500 shillings payment made, title: You have paid, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `"content_available":` true on your notification payload.
Try this payload to send notification.

```
{ 
"to": "your title name", 
"content_available": true,
 "notification": {
 "title": "TITLE TEXT", 
"body": "BODY TEXT",
 "content_available": true
 },
 "data": { 
"body": "BODY TEXT",
 "title": "TITLE TEXT", 
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks shirsh. My problem was providing null values to title and body in the notification.
{
 notification: {
  title: null,
  body: null,
 },
 data: {
  intent: payment,
  body: "BODY TEXT",
  title: "TITLE TEXT",
  click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK
 }
}

Comment: if is is helpful then set this as accept answer(blue tick)this.